# Scanning Multiple barcodes of various types and orientations and storing in sql with php

Tags: barcode, scanning

I have been thinking about creating a web-based application that is able to read multiple barcodes (various formats and orientations) from an image file or device.

Subsequently I want to store these barcodes in a database.

I have been looking at various similar questions for the last few days and do not believe that the available libraries will be able to perform this function.

(based on the following threads: [Scan multiple barcodes with ZXing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628373/scan-multiple-barcodes-with-zxing), [Read multiple barcode from a single image using php or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723550/read-multiple-barcode-from-a-single-image-using-php-or-javascript))

The hp idol ondemand is only able to scan images with horizontal barcodes (that too poorly). The http://www.dynamsoft.com/Demo/DBR/BarcodeReaderDemo.aspx is only able to read images that they have posted, my images do not return any barcodes.

Thought I should post this to get some feedback from other members before I head too far down this path.

Comment: No barcode SDK can provide 100% detection rate. Have you tested other images with the Dynamsoft online demo? Have you tried ZBar (open source) or other commercial SDKs?

Comment: Can you provide any examples of the barcode images you are trying to read from? (I work for HP. Feel free to email sample image files to idolondemand@hp.com if you'd like the team to investigate further.).

Comment: Commodity phone doesn't have the ideal hardware for scanning barcodes. Ideally the app is accessed using mobile device with dedicated scanner like [these](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/mobile-computers/handheld.html). Even then accuracy and speed can only guaranteed if you can limit the symbology beforehand.

Comment: @Martheen I think the issue is that rm65453 wants to be able to recognize multiple barcodes in a single "scan". As far as I am aware, those purpose built scanners only read/process a single barcode at a time.

Comment: Ouch, missed that point. Some imaging sensor can do it, poorly. Meh, it's not really workable in my opinion unless the user put their flagship phone on a tripod in a well-lit room.